# JavaFX call method in Button with the correst String from List

Tags: java, list, selenium, button, javafx

i am new here, am new in programming and i am trying to create a Java app with Selenium and JavaFX. In this app i should be able to check the links of a page and also could be able to show the pointed link. For the moment the programm can check all the links on a page but it can't show the correct link. I display all urls in a ListView with a button and in this buttons calls the method to show the link but for every button in the list it always shows the same url/link because it is the last value taken from the variable `url` in a while loop. And also i have 4 tabs where i track the HTTP Status of each link. For all 200 HTTP status they are inserted in the "200s" tab, for the 300 in the "300s" tab, the same for the 400 and 500. I have a variable `respCode` for the HTTP status but it always displays the last value in the while loop (200). Here is a code snippet to have a look on it:

```
public class AutoTestController
    {
    // location and resources will be automatically injected by the FXML loader
        @FXML
        private Button buttonSearch;

        @FXML
        private Button buttonCheck;

        @FXML
        private Button buttonAllLinks;

        @FXML
        private ChoiceBox switchLogin;

        @FXML
        private TextField testUrl;

        @FXML
        private TextField stageUrl;

        @FXML
        private TextField stageIntUrl;

        @FXML
        private TextField testUrlLiveInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField testUrlStage;

        @FXML
        private TextField testUrlStageInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField customerIdLogin;

        @FXML
        private TextField customerIdLoginLiveInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField oneCustomerIdLoginLiveInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField customerIdLoginStage;

        @FXML
        private TextField customerIdLoginStageInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField oneCustomerIdLoginStageInt;

        @FXML
        private PasswordField passwordLogin;

        @FXML
        private PasswordField passwordLoginStage;

        @FXML
        private PasswordField onePasswordLoginLiveInt;

        @FXML
        private PasswordField onePasswordLoginStageInt;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkText;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextTwo;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextThree;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextFour;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextFive;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextEmpty;

        @FXML
        private TextField linkTextAnother;

        @FXML
        private int textLinks;

        @FXML
        private ChoiceBox countrySelector;

        @FXML
        private ChoiceBox countrySelectorLiveInt;

        @FXML
        private StackPane paneTwo;

        @FXML
        private StackPane paneThree;

        @FXML
        private StackPane paneFour;

        @FXML
        private StackPane paneFive;

        private static WebDriver driver = null;

        @FXML
        private int respCode = 200;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCount=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountTwo=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountThree=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountFour=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountFive=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountEmpty=0;

        @FXML
        private static int linkCountAnother=0;

        @FXML
        private String url = "";

        private int counter=0;

        private ObservableList<String> listTwo;

        private ObservableList<String> listThree;

        private ObservableList<String> listFour;

        private ObservableList<String> listFive;

        private List<String> urlsTwo = new ArrayList<>();

        private List list = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<String[]> urlsTwo2 = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<String> urlsThree = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<String> urlsFour = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<String> urlsFive = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add a public no-args constructor
        public AutoTestController()
        {

        }

        public class XCell extends ListCell<String> {
            HBox hB = new HBox();
            Label label = new Label("Empty");
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            Button bB = new Button("Show Link");
            String lastItem = "";

            public XCell() {
                super();
                hB.getChildren().addAll(bB, new Text(" (" + respCode + ") : "), label, pane, new Text(" "));
                HBox.setHgrow(paneTwo, Priority.ALWAYS);
                bB.setUserData(url);
                bB.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent eventTwo) {
                        Button thisButton = (Button) eventTwo.getSource();
                        WebElement linkTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '" + thisButton.getUserData() + "')]"));
                        scrolltoElement(linkTwo);
                        HighlightThisLink(driver, linkTwo);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(null);  // No text in label of super class
                if (empty) {
                    lastItem = null;
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    lastItem = item;
                    label.setText(item!=null ? item : "<null>");
                    setGraphic(hB);
                }
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void initialize()
        {
            countrySelector.getItems().addAll("DE","US","CA","UK","FR","ES","IT","MX");
            countrySelector.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
            countrySelectorLiveInt.getItems().addAll("DE","US","CA","UK","FR","ES","IT","MX");
            countrySelectorLiveInt.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        }

        @FXML
        private void CheckLink(){
            String theUrl = "";

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

            HttpURLConnection huc = null;

            driver.navigate();

            List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            linkCount = links.size();

            System.out.println("Total Links on Page : "+linkCount);
            linkText.setText("Total Links on Page : " + linkCount);


            Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

                if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
                    linkCountEmpty++;
                    System.out.println("Number of empty urls : " + linkCountEmpty);
                    linkTextEmpty.setText("Number of empty urls : " + linkCountEmpty);
                    continue;
                }

                if(!url.startsWith(theUrl)){
                    System.out.println("URL " + url + " belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
                    linkCountAnother++;
                    System.out.println("Number of another domain : " + linkCountAnother);
                    linkTextAnother.setText("Number of other : " + linkCountAnother);
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

                    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                    huc.connect();

                    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

                    if(respCode >= 200 && respCode <= 226) {
                        urlsTwo.add(url);
                        listTwo = FXCollections.observableArrayList(urlsTwo);
                        ListView<String> lvTwo = new ListView<>(listTwo);
                            lvTwo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                                @Override
                                public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                                    return new XCell();
                                }
                            });
                            paneTwo.getChildren().add(lvTwo);
                        System.out.println(respCode+": "+url+" is a success link");
                        linkCountTwo++;
                        System.out.println("Number of 200s : " + linkCountTwo);
                        linkTextTwo.setText("Number of 200s : " + linkCountTwo);
                    }

                    if(respCode >= 300 && respCode <= 308) {
                        urlsThree.add(url);
                        listThree = FXCollections.observableArrayList(urlsThree);
                        ListView<String> lvThree = new ListView<>(listThree);
                        lvThree.setUserData(respCode);
                        lvThree.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                                return new XCell();
                            }
                        });
                        paneThree.getChildren().add(lvThree);
                        System.out.println(respCode+": "+url+" is a redirection link");
                        linkCountThree++;
                        System.out.println("Number of 300s : " + linkCountThree);
                        linkTextThree.setText("Number of 300s : " + linkCountThree);
                    }

                    if(respCode >= 400 && respCode <= 499) {
                        urlsFour.add(url);
                        listFour = FXCollections.observableArrayList(urlsFour);
                        ListView<String> lvFour = new ListView<>(listFour);
                        lvFour.setUserData(respCode);
                        lvFour.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                                return new XCell();
                            }
                        });
                        paneFour.getChildren().add(lvFour);
                        System.out.println(respCode+": "+url+" is a client error link");
                        linkCountFour++;
                        System.out.println("Number of 400s : " + linkCountFour);
                        linkTextFour.setText("Number of 400s : " + linkCountFour);
                    }

                    if(respCode >= 500 && respCode <= 599) {
                        urlsFive.add(url);
                        listFive = FXCollections.observableArrayList(urlsFive);
                        ListView<String> lvFive = new ListView<>(listFive);
                        lvFive.setUserData(respCode);
                        lvFive.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                                return new XCell();
                            }
                        });
                        paneFive.getChildren().add(lvFive);
                        System.out.println(respCode+": "+url+" is a server error link");
                        linkCountFive++;
                        System.out.println("Number of 200s : " + linkCountFive);
                        linkTextFive.setText("Number of 200s : " + linkCountFive);
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

 public static void scrolltoElement(WebElement ScrolltoThisElement) {
        Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable) ScrolltoThisElement).getCoordinates();
        coordinate.onPage();
        coordinate.inViewPort();
    }


    @FXML
    private void HighlightThisLink(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        driver.navigate();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
        try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 2px white')", element);
        }
}
```

Here is a capture of the programm with JavaFX:
[Link Checker Programm 200s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDgwL.png)
[Link Checker Programm 300s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ash9V.png)

Could someone please help with these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to understand the way `ListView` works:

A `ListView` creates the cells that are required to display the items when they are needed. You don't control yourself when this is done. You should be able to deal with cell creation happening at any time. There is no 1:1 relation between cells and items. Items may be reassigned to different cells and there may not be a cell for every item.

For this reason retrieving info in `cellFactory` (which is what you do in your cell constructor) will not work.

You should change the item type allowing you to access all neccessary info and use the `ListCell.item` property in the `Button` handler of the cell:

```
private static class Response {
    private final int responseCode;
    private final String url;

    Response(int responseCode, String url) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
        this.url = url;
    }

    // getters...

}

private static class XCell extends ListCell<Response> {
    private final HBox hB = new HBox();
    private final Label label = new Label("Empty");
    private final Button bB = new Button("Show Link");
    private final Text response = new Text();

    public XCell() {
        hB.getChildren().addAll(bB, response, label);
        bB.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent eventTwo) {
                // handle button click using info from cell item
                Response item = getItem();
                WebElement linkTwo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '" + item.getUrl() + "')]"));
                scrolltoElement(linkTwo);
                HighlightThisLink(driver, linkTwo);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Response item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        // update display
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            label.setText(item.getUrl());
            response.setText("("+Integer.toString(item.getResponseCode()) + "):");
            setGraphic(hB);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    listTwo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<Response> lvTwo = new ListView<>(listTwo);
    lvTwo.setCellFactory(lv ->  new XCell());
    paneTwo.getChildren().add(lvTwo);

    listThree = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<Response> lvThree = new ListView<>(listThree);
    lvThree.setCellFactory(l -> new XCell());
    paneThree.getChildren().add(lvThree);

    listFour = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<Response> lvFour = new ListView<>(listFour);
    lvFour.setCellFactory(l -> new XCell());
    paneFour.getChildren().add(lvFour);

    listFive = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<Response> lvFive = new ListView<>(listFive);
    lvFive.setCellFactory(l -> new XCell());
    paneFive.getChildren().add(lvFive);

    ...
}
```

```
try {
    huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

    huc.connect();

    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

    switch (respCode / 100) {
        case 2:
            if (respCode <= 226) {
                listTwo.add(new Response(respCode, url));
                System.out.println(respCode+": "+url+" is a success link");
                linkCountTwo++;
                System.out.println("Number of 200s : " + linkCountTwo);
                linkTextTwo.setText("Number of 200s : " + linkCountTwo);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (respCode <= 308) {
                listThree.add(new Response(respCode, url));
                ...
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            listFour.add(new Response(respCode, url));
            ...
            break;
        case 5:
            listFive.add(new Response(respCode, url));
            ...
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Fabian first of all thank you with your help i really appreciate your code helps me a lot. Now i got the problem that the 'XCell' class cannot extends the 'Response' class because XCell can only extend a String and not 2 parameters.

Comment: This was a copy&paste error. I did not change the type parameter of every `ListView` to `Response`.

Comment: Hi Fabian i don't know why but for some reason there is an error for the ListView as seen here:

listTwo = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<Response> lvTwo = new ListView<>(listTwo);
        lvTwo.setCellFactory(lv ->  new XCell());
        paneTwo.getChildren().add(lvTwo);

The arguments '<>' of ListView<>(listTwo) are marked as an error and also in the switch case this part:
'listTwo.add(new Response(respCode, url));'
 is also marked as an error because a string (java.lang.String) is expected and not a class (Response).

Comment: @BorisFongan you need to change the declaration of the `ObservableList` fields to `ObservbleList<Response>`

Comment: Yeah i made it after my own comment. I am off today sorry. Thanks for your explanation.